# Is there a way of writing switch statements or other solutions for querySelectors?

Tags: javascript

I currently have

```
if (element.querySelector('h1:first-child') || element.querySelector('container')) {
     removeBorderClass();
}

if (element.querySelector('h3:first-child')) {
     removeBorderClass();
}
```

But obviously this is a bad practice in JavaScript.

Can I use Switch case

```
switch(element.querySelector())
     case 'h3:first-child' || 'container'
     break;
//this is an example
```

or is there even better solution for this?

```
<section>
    <h1>h1 is first child of section</h1>
    //it should remove the border
</section>

<section>
    <h2>h1 is first child of section</h2>
    //it should not remove the border
</section>
```

Comment: You want to perform an action based on whether or not an element has children matching specific rules?

Comment: Yes that is right, so if section element contains h1 as first child - it removes border - for example.

Comment: Why do you say this is bad practice in JavaScript? Your code is very clear as it is.

Comment: because you don't want the application to read the multiple if statements in javascript, which can increase loading time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use switch/case like that, if that pattern repeats a lot, you may refactor it into a function of its own:

```
function ifHasMatchingChildren(parent, selectors, callback) {
    // or, if you want to get fancy
 // if (selectors.some(parent.querySelector.bind(parent)) {
    if (selectors.some(selector => parent.querySelector(selector))) {
        return callback();
    }
}

ifHasMatchingChildren(element, ['h1:first-child', 'container'], () => 
    removeBorderClass());
// can even be shortened with the following
ifHasMatchingChildren(element, ['h3:first-child'], removeBorderClass);
```

Comment: Might combining the selectors into a selector-list (as a now-deleted answer demonstrated) improve performance any? At the very least it'd save having to call querySelector once per selector, but does that have meaningful performance gains?

Comment: @BoltClock: It would not (significantly). Querying the DOM multiple times like that has no penalty unless the DOM is changed between calls.